# Testing a class that uses $inject property notation in its functions

Tags: angularjs

I need to modify a constant service. This service has no tests attached, but I wanted to, at least partially, cover the file and my modifications with unit tests that I will write with Jasmine.

The service looks like:

```
(function () {
    angular
   .module('app')
   .constant('myService', myService);

   function myService() {
       dependencyOne: dependencyOneImpl,
       someFunction: someFunctionImpl
       ...
   }

   dependencyOneImpl.$inject = ['someDependency'];
   function dependencyOneImpl(someDependency) {
       ...
   }

   someFunctionImpl.$inject = ['dependencyOne', 'dependencyTwo'];
   function someFunctionImpl(dependencyOne, dependencyTwo) {
       ...
   } 
})();
```

It is used in the resolution process of routes (we use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)). When a particular route is activated, a function of the service is invoked:

```
someRoute = {
    url: '...',
    name: '...'
    views: { ... },
    resolve: { resolver.someFunction }
}
```

There are no dependencies required in the construction of the service, and I'm trying to test one of the public functions that the service exposes.

Typically I would write the test like:

```
prepareSomeSetup();
theService.someFunction();
assertSomething();
```

I could manually resolve the dependencies required by the function, but I would like to know if I can get the same behavior that ui-router is getting when resolving the function. The dependencies seem to be resolved and the function is executed.

It crossed my mind that I probably needed to inject $injector service in the test file and manually call invoke somehow to resolve the function, but it does not seem to work.

How can I call the function with the two dependencies resolved?

Comment: Whether you use $inject, the array notation, or the simple, non-minifiable notation doesn't change anything to how you get an instance of your service. You use inject(constantsService), and angular will create the dependencies of the service inject them in the service itself, and inject the service in your function. What does not work, precisely?

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet!, maybe I exposed the whole thing wrong. When I want to exercise my SUT, which in this case would be a function, all the dependencies are undefined (as I'm not providing any parameters). Let me update the question.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why don't you post the actual, complete code of the service and the actual, complete code of the test, and the error you get? As I said, the dependencies **should** be resolved.

Comment: Sorry @JBNizet, not sure if I'm being very successful at explaining. When I call to the function in my test, the function that has two dependencies, those dependencies will be undefined inside. 

Which it is obvious to some extent I guess, as I'm not providing any parameter. Could it be that I shoudn't be calling to the function that way?

Comment: It seems you're not trying to test the service, but instead the constructor of the service. That is usually unnecessary, because a service constructor typically doesn't do anything other than storing the dependencies. It would be much clearer if you posted the complete actual code, as already asked several times. Since we have no idea at all of what the function is doing, it's hard to give proper advice. Post the code.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to replicate how Angular DI works instead of making `someFunction` a factory service?

Comment: I really hope that makes more sense now. What I was trying to express is that I'm trying to test one of the functions that the service is exposing. All of the functions of the service have parameters that are injected via $inject. The dependencies are not specified in the constructor. Is it looking better?

Comment: But how is it used? What code are you testing? If it is used with `$injector.invoke`, it should be tested in the same manner. It isn't clear from the code why someFunction isn't a `provider` `$get` or `factory`, both would do DI for you.

Comment: Inject the two dependencies in your test (thanks to the inject() function), and call `theService.someFunction(dependencyOne, dependencyTwo);`. Or create two fake dependencies and call the service with these fake dependencies. The function expects two arguments, so you should call it with two arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define an injectable function you have to call it using `$injector.invoke(fn, scope, otherArgs);`

Where

- fn the injectable function, or array for inline injection
- scope : the "this" of the function
- otherArgs : others Arguments that are not defined as service,... in angular that you inject.

Comment: Thank you @walfrat! :). My problem is that some of the dependencies of the method are defined in the same file, as other functions. As you can see in the code, 'dependencyOne' is defined in the same file. When I use the injector.invoke, it fails because he is not able to find 'dependencyOne'. As you said, I can provide it in otherArgs, but the problem is that I need to manually resolve the dependencies, and sometimes it can be complex (I have bigger lists and with deeper compositions that the one depicted in the example). Any way to avoid this?

Comment: In your code dependencyOne is never added to the angular environement. Only myService is added through the `.service` method. So you need either to make your dependency one an angular service, or inject `myService` where you need and use `myService.dependencyOne`. Did you enabled strict DI mod in angular ? If you don't define $inject or use inline injection lie `["a", function(a){}]` strict DI should crash your code. Because this won't work when minification will be done